# Installing Tkinter to use on Pycharm on a Mac

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I just downloaded Pycharm because Spyder on Anaconda wasn't working anymore on my Mac. I am trying use Tkinter and have tried to run code using both

```
from tkinter import *
```

and

```
import tkinter as tk
```

The second is from my python class. Both times it returns

```
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

I have tried to search for "tkinter" on Python Interpreter but there's no solid "tkinter." Only others like tkinter.math. Please help.

Comment: tkinter is part of the standard python installation. This is surprising you do not have it. Pycharm is just an editor. Did you try running python from any console?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter would not be visible on Python Interpreter since it is a part of standard Python installation, the only additional modules or packages which user downloads are visible in Settings. Since, Spyder on your PC is not working as well, make sure python is installed properly and is configured correctly with path details properly set up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the interpreter of PyCharm.
Or Reinstall the python package and make a virtual environment.